# compute size of DataTemplate-Generated Elements without drawing them

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

```
 public class Notifications: ObservableCollection < Notification > {}
 public Notifications Notifications = new Notifications();
 private readonly Queue < Notification > buffer = new Queue < Notification > ();

 public NotificationsWindows() {
    InitializeComponent();
    NotificationsControl.DataContext = Notifications;
    this.Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
    this.Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width / 3;
    this.Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Left + SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - this.Width;
    this.Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Top;
 }

 public void AddNotification(Notification notification) {
    notification.Id = count++;

    if (NotificationsControl.ActualHeight + * what would be the size of the notification we want to add * > SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height) {
        buffer.Enqueue(notification);
    } else {
        if (corner == 0 || corner == 3) {
            Notifications.Insert(0, notification);
        } else {
            Notifications.Add(notification);
        }
    }

    //Show window if there're notifications
    if (Notifications.Count > 0 && !IsActive) Show();
 }
```

The following code is in a WPF window class, and NotificationsControl is an item control that apply a data template over the « Notifications » collection.
I'm trying to show desktop alerts on the screen that would stop when using all the screen's height, so I need to compute what would be the size of the Notification when applied to the data template. Is it possible ?

Comment: Take a look at the Measure and Arrange methods in this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058(v=vs.110).aspx#LayoutSystem_Measure_Arrange) page. If you run these methods after the datacontext has been updated, then you can get the new size. If it's larger than you'd like, remove the notification from the datacontext. I used this method once with Label sizes, it should work with other UIElements as well.

Comment: @Attila thanks i got it working using MeasureOverride :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Attila that showed where to search.

I overrided MeasureOverride to add back the notification into buffer if the control.DesiredSize exceeded Form's Height

```
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        Size ret = base.MeasureOverride(finalSize);
        Debug.WriteLine(NotificationsControl.DesiredSize);

        if (NotificationsControl.DesiredSize.Height >= Height && Notifications.Count > 0)
        {
            int index;
            if (corner == 0 || corner == 3)
            {
                index = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                index = Notifications.Count - 1;
            }
            buffer.Insert(0,Notifications[index]);
            Notifications.RemoveAt(index);
            InvalidateMeasure();
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Not sure if InvalidateMeasure() is needed tho